# Solve equation by shooting method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I've got homework to numerical methods to solve this equation using shooting method

$ y'' - (1-e^{-x})y = 0, \quad y(0) = 1, \quad y(x\to+\infty) = 0 $

Hints I've got:

1. Easily you can find asymptotic solution, using this solution you can use functional substition, that will reduce functional values of solution
2. You can use substition of independent variable to make integration domain finite interval.
3. Hints above also say: Graph of function is unbounded in $x$ and $y$ axis. Using suitable  substitution you can make graph bounded in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Can anyone help me with transformations? Thanks!

Comment: Try $\displaystyle t = {\rm e}^{-x}$ as the new independent variable first. It’ll map your infinity interval toward the $\displaystyle\left[0,1\right]$ interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part 1, they want you to note that if $y$ is unbounded, it grows asymptotically as $e^x$. Therefore, $e^{-x}y(x)$ will be bounded. Letting $z(x) = e^{-x}y(x)$, we find that
$$
z''(x) +2 z'(x) +e^{-x}z(x)= 0\;\;\;;\;\;\;z(0) = 1\;\;\;;\;\;\;z(\infty) = 0.
$$
For part 2, the infinite interval on $x$ needs to be reduced to a finite one. The equation itself suggests something like $u = e^{-x}$. Let's use $u = 1-e^{-x}$ so that the transform is increasing. Letting $z(x) =  w(1-e^{-x})$ gives
$$
(1-u) w''(u) + w'(u) +w(u) = 0\;\;\;;\;\;\; w(0) = 1\;\;\;;\;\;\;w(1) = 0.
$$
Now you can try different initial conditions for $w'(0)$ and see which ones get $w(1)$ close to $0$. Of course, you can't actually do calculations at $u=1$ because of the singular point, but you can force $w(1-\epsilon) = 0$ for some small $\epsilon$. You can then recover $y'(0)$ using $y'(0) = w'(0)+w(0)$.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I solve it by shooting method, if I have equation with second degree of $y$. I can solve it only for first degree $y$. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can not integrate over infinite intervals. So you have to set an upper limit $b$ and establish some boundary condition there.

The limit point is a saddle point. There are exactly 2 paths that lead to it in the phase portrait, and any deviation from these will at some point exponentially diverge.

For $x>b$ the factor $e^{-x}$ becomes very small, for a suitably large $b$. The reduced equation $y''-y=0$ has known solutions, aka "far-field solutions". The one that remains bounded satisfies $y'+y=0$. Thus you can take $y'(b)+y(b)=0$ as upper boundary condition.

---

To get higher accuracy, or the same accuracy with a smaller $b$, compute the next perturbation term in $y=c_0e^{-x}+c_1e^{-2x}+...$ to get
$$
-3c_1e^{-2x}+...=c_0e^{-2x}+c_1e^{-3x}+...
$$
Thus an improved boundary condition is $$(3-e^{-b})y'(b)+(3+2e^{-b})y(b)=0.$$

Comment: Thank you! If I'm right, now I have to just solve equation by trying different $b$? Or what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: The idea is to have some fixed $b$, values $[5,10,20]$ should be quite sufficient, and solve the IVP with initial conditions $[1,v]$ and the boundary condition, or rather its error or residual, as function of $v$. Here this is a scalar function, the equation is linear, so one or two secant steps should give the correct solution within sensible error tolerances. You can compare the solution and far-field continuation for several $b$, the difference should be in the scale of $e^{-b}$.